# GET vs POST in HTTP

Tags: http, caching, web

Imagine I have a library of books, each with a genre.  Each of these books is stored in my database.  My website allows users to retrieve lists of books that exist in the library by searching on any permutation of different genres. I know that certain searches will occur more than others, so the results are pre-computed and cached.  Other searches are far more rare, and I am comfortable hitting the database on request and then caching the result afterwards in the database. The client does not know which queries have been cached and which have not, and thus it does not know if the server will make DB changes or not. So how does the client know whether to GET or POST?

A few clarifications

1. My queries are far more complicated that just genre. There are many factors besides genre that can compose a query, but I am keeping the example simple. Long story short, I cannot precompute and cache all possible queries.
2. Everyone says code first, optimize later. Heeding this advice, I am not caching the DB results in memory using memcache or redis.  Rather, I am simply storing the results of my queries in special DB tables.  Is this okay?

Any thoughts or words of advice on my situation?

Comment: Title and content do not match I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Java / JPA solution for your web application, then this caching is all built.

Have a look at this http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/eclipse

Comment: I am using Djangp, which does not innately support caching.

Comment: I had thought that it hinged on using memcache, but it looks like there are other options as well. I'll check them out. Thank you